# Выгрузка данных в Excel

Tags: java, javafx

Запросом получаю данные в ResultSet. Как полученные данные выгрузить в Excel и сразу же открыть полученный Excel файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это две отдельные задачи.

**Формирование Excel файла**

Для этого есть множество библиотек. Самые популярные из них Apache POI и Jasper Reports.

Пример с использованием Apache POI:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ApachePOIExcelWrite {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");
        Object[][] datatypes = {
                {"Datatype", "Type", "Size(in bytes)"},
                {"int", "Primitive", 2},
                {"float", "Primitive", 4},
                {"double", "Primitive", 8},
                {"char", "Primitive", 1},
                {"String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixed size"}
        };

        int rowNum = 0;
        System.out.println("Creating excel");

        for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Object field : datatype) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                if (field instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

**Запуск Excel с передачей ему результирующего файла**

Так же можно решить разными способами. Один из них - передача сигнала системе о том, что нужно открыть файл просмотрщиком по умолчанию.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx"));
```

В таком случае либо запустится Excel, либо появится системный диалог выбора программы для открытия файла.

Comment: Отличная библиотека..